# Ember template convention

Tags: javascript, ember.js, discourse

I'm trying to understand EmberJS template convention in [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/).
Here's a snippet from `app/assets/javascripts/discourse/templates/discovery/categories.hbs`

```
{{#discovery-categories refresh="refresh"}}
  {{component controller.categoryPageStyle
              categories=model.categories
              latestTopicOnly=controller.latestTopicOnly
              topics=model.topics}}
  {{!-- my-template --}}
{{/discovery-categories}}
```

What is the meaning of `discovery-categories` and `component`?
For example I want to insert `my-template` to extend `categories.hbs`, what is the convention I should use to create file with my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `discovery-categories` is the name of the component which is
   called statically using the name of the component.
2. Whereas in the second line 'component' is a template helper which loads the component dynamically using the name specified via property `controller.categoryPageStyle`.

3.my-template is the yield block , where you can have context of the component `discovery-categories` if its yield.
 for eg. if `discovery-categories` has a property `foo` you can write something like

```
{{#discovery-categories refresh="refresh" foo="Some Text"}}
  {{component controller.categoryPageStyle
              categories=model.categories
              latestTopicOnly=controller.latestTopicOnly
              topics=model.topics}}
  {{foo}}
{{/discovery-categories}}
```

Comment: I cant find `discovery-categories` component in [discours](http://www.discourse.org/) src code ?.

Comment: Their current source code as of i write is in this file https://discourse-cdn.global.ssl.fastly.net/try/assets/application-38979d6a8c030cb6fbab15d279375c5dbf5a90988362baa408337c1cb0ee5cc3.js if you search for `discovery-categories` you can see it , its defined like this `define("discourse/components/discovery-categories"` since its a compiled code we cant make out exactly what it does.